# stream context create php to node js

Tags: php, node.js, https, request, http-headers

I'm trying to get data from a site using node js axios or https, but so far no results.

In PHP I have the following code that does return data from the request. I was using curl but it didn't work and I decided to use stream_context_create and that worked for me.

I am browsing the internet, there is something similar to using stream_context_create but I have not found any results. I also asked chat gpt but it didn't help either.

PHP code

```
function doCurl($request_type, $url, $params, $header){
    $opts = array('http' =>
        array(
            'method'  => $request_type,
            'header'  => $header,
            'content' => $params,
        )
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    return file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
}
  
$url = 'https://www.expedia.com/graphql';

$params = '{
    "query": "query CarSearchV3($context: ContextInput!, $primaryCarSearchCriteria: PrimaryCarCriteriaInput!, $secondaryCriteria: ShoppingSearchCriteriaInput!, $shoppingContext: ShoppingContextInput) {\n  carSearchOrRecommendations(\n    context: $context\n    primaryCarSearchCriteria: .......",
    "variables": {
        "context": {
            "siteId": 1,
            "locale": "en_US",
            "eapid": 0,
            "currency": "USD",
            "device": {
                "type": "DESKTOP"
            },
            "identity": {
                "duaid": "66f18af8-5ac4-46e6-b904-e297a8851b49",
                "expUserId": "-1",
                "tuid": "-1",
                "authState": "ANONYMOUS"
            },
            "privacyTrackingState": "CAN_TRACK",
            "debugContext": {
                "abacusOverrides": [],
                "alterMode": "RELEASED"
            }
        },
        "primaryCarSearchCriteria": {
            "pickUpLocation": {
                "searchTerm": "Cancun, Quintana Roo, Mexico (CUN-Cancun Intl.)",
                "regionId": "5133635",
                "isExactLocationSearch": false
            },
            "pickUpDateTime": {
                "day": 25,
                "month": 10,
                "year": 2023,
                "hour": 10,
                "minute": 30,
                "second": 0
            },
            "dropOffDateTime": {
                "day": 26,
                "month": 10,
                "year": 2023,
                "hour": 10,
                "minute": 30,
                "second": 0
            }
        },
        "secondaryCriteria": {
            "booleans": [
                {
                    "id": "SALES_UNLOCKED",
                    "value": false
                }
            ],
            "selections": [
                {
                    "id": "searchId",
                    "value": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        "shoppingContext": null
    },
    "operationName": "CarSearchV3"
}';

$ContentLength = strlen($params);

$header = "Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n"
    . "Host:www.expedia.com\r\n"
    . "Cookie:DUAID=d1734106-bd58-4e74-89d2-99dff48e7e48; EG_SESSIONTOKEN=dFwbH9wUtGtv7ZPiLl9ioAUGQjiKPMwW9B2o8EB1vIhcZA:JS20Hcx-PgBe2QFwWDZgdd5qZItokfbmCA6y35AKBhwQ3VlFFfWR6qUmaAyGYRuOEgrSpjr25MlX6uguiKdHWQ; HMS=898665d2-6016-412f-956d-bb74053e4d24; MC1=GUID=d1734106bd584e7489d299dff48e7e48; _abck=C9F43A19120F2D1C0F7D5068F0458924~-1~YAAQJKzBFxdpZvyKAQAARinRIQoBsMIv3QP6zIFVPRMYZKDRlxGPriXGJ+8WlkZuG/TJaXt2hQaRc+ZV7RTFQdB/v3LQBPf5NTPKAV4mNb1Okdu+9okttOdwvRtr83sE1oL7E1tpj7OUSpi2pEeIoIbUH14A6lB1AVH0ff7LIh/G6nJw7NERjI95AaYAkDtLfP6Fm71pNOId2jPav5O+6A8Ccg9uvHWZrpXPpCXp6a6lfsFx3iqDqjsCY6nYeU4Lhb4ZW/ctIy81zpxkHobutbomPf70xKbpRZvC4vch9p+bjelgzH8cJ0Dq3lwgHbU1FNZPg0bZqZAjyEH41FE3b5zKo/ARnDUsgtEbWkxvkcPCfQ6F5bgZh7bG6Q2gkdR9s/1IpxIsxPEPEkfm~-1~-1~-1; bm_sz=198D8A179382445192C51158EBA50EAB~YAAQJKzBFxhpZvyKAQAARinRIRWYMd2gkl5iyrGT7D/whjippsb+NMq0u08GVcIX51kisIr15qEK+hcUO5pq18SGm8gtzTCWzXBp7Fp6d6XqGKvcmp6mOAPbolgd6nNiTWXgkgppQu1MyoHLQ6vI4GGwJNiSZLcWyiBBKohGWtGW+nM9oqtfNA7eHAC3zi63raUxf9eoOXGCsaWE2lha0DcgA+vfwFu3qnMgYG0gvozgINjE8N/alkBXckUhxGyNrJ2wqxb7bKXAXzLqFkbqzKmms2BA9EhikwicPgS4Sin2BjV1~4473654~4277574; cesc=%7B%22marketingClick%22%3A%5B%22false%22%2C1697061579269%5D%2C%22hitNumber%22%3A%5B%226%22%2C1697061579269%5D%2C%22visitNumber%22%3A%5B%221%22%2C1697061155070%5D%2C%22entryPage%22%3A%5B%22page.Car-Search%22%2C1697061579269%5D%7D\r\n"
    . "Client-Info:bernie-cars-shopping-web,pwa,us-east-1\r\n"
    . "Content-Length:" . $ContentLength;

$response = doCurl("POST", $url, $params, $header);

echo "Response: ";
var_dump(json_decode($response));
```

This is the node axios js code

```
const axios = require('axios');
let data = `{
  "query": "query CarSearchV3($context: ContextInput!, $primaryCarSearchCriteria: PrimaryCarCriteriaInput!, $secondaryCriteria: ShoppingSearchCriteriaInput!, $shoppingContext: ShoppingContextInput) {\n  carSearchOrRecommendations(\n    context: $context\n    primaryCarSearchCriteria: $primaryCarSearchCriteria\n    secondaryCriteria: $secondaryCriteria\n    shoppingContext: $shoppingContext\n  ) {\n    carSearchResults {\n      shoppingContext {\n        multiItem {\n          id\n        }\n      }\n      carsShoppingContext {\n        searchId\n      }\n      multiItemAnchorPriceToken\n      multiItemPickUpDropOffMessage {\n        message {\n          __typename\n          ... on CarPhraseText {\n            text\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      multiItemPlayBackTitleBar {\n        primary {\n          __typename\n          ... on CarPhraseText {\n            text\n          }\n        }\n        secondary {\n          longMessage {\n            __typename\n            ... on CarPhraseText {\n              text\n            }\n          }\n          shortMessage {\n            __typename\n            ... on CarPhraseText {\n              text\n            }\n          }\n          accessibilityMessage {\n            __typename\n            ... on CarPhraseText {\n              text\n            }\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      listings {\n        __typename\n        ... on CarMessagingCard {\n          ...messagingCard\n        }\n        ... on CarOfferCard {\n          accessibilityString\n          offerBadges {\n            ...badge\n          }\n          vehicle {\n            image {\n              ...image\n            }\n            ecoFriendlyFuel {\n              ... on CarsRichText {\n                value\n                style\n                theme\n              }\n            }\n            category\n            categoryIcon {\n              ...icon\n            }\n            description\n            attributes {\n              icon {\n                ...icon\n              }\n              text\n            }\n            features {\n              ...feature\n            }\n            fuelInfo {\n              ...feature\n            }\n          }\n          tripLocations {\n            pickUpLocation {\n              ...carOfferVendorLocationInfo\n            }\n            dropOffLocation {\n              ...carOfferVendorLocationInfo\n            }\n          }\n          vendor {\n            image {\n              ...image\n            }\n          }\n          detailsContext {\n            carOfferToken\n            selectedAccessories\n            rewardPointsSelection\n            continuationContextualId\n          }\n          priceBadges {\n            ...badge\n          }\n          actionableConfidenceMessages {\n            ...carPhrase\n          }\n          review {\n            rating\n            superlative\n            totalCount\n            richRatingText {\n              ...detailsRichText\n            }\n          }\n          priceSummary {\n            ...offerPriceSummary\n          }\n          shortList {\n            favorited\n            saveUrl\n            removeUrl\n          }\n          action {\n            ...carAction\n          }\n          reserveButtonText\n          infositeURL {\n            relativePath\n          }\n          offerHeading\n          multiItemPriceToken\n          additionalBenefits {\n            ...carPhrase\n          }\n          cancellationAndPaymentMessages {\n            ...carPhrase\n          }\n          clubbedPriceOptions {\n            dialogTrigger {\n              ...carActionableItem\n            }\n            dialogContent {\n              title\n              vendor {\n                image {\n                  ...image\n                }\n              }\n              vehicleCategory\n              vehicleDescription\n              optionsSummary {\n                ...carPhrase\n              }\n              clubbedPrices {\n                heading {\n                  ...carPhrase\n                }\n                title {\n                  ...carPhrase\n                }\n                offerBadges {\n                  ...badge\n                }\n                priceBadges {\n                  ...badge\n                }\n                priceSummary {\n                  ...offerPriceSummary\n                }\n                paymentMessages {\n                  ...carPhrase\n                }\n                additionalPaymentMessages {\n                  ...carPhrase\n                }\n                cancellationMessages {\n                  ...carPhrase\n                }\n                additionalBenefits {\n                  ...carPhrase\n                }\n                loyaltyEarnMessages {\n                  ...carPhrase\n                }\n                reserveButtonAction {\n                  ...carAction\n                }\n                reserveButtonText\n                infositeURL {\n                  relativePath\n                }\n              }\n              commonAdditionalBenefits {\n                ...carPhrase\n              }\n              modalFooter\n            }\n          }\n          isFareComparisonTestEnabled\n          priceSummaryText\n          enhancedCleanlinessDialog {\n            images {\n              value\n            }\n            title\n            description\n            content {\n              title {\n                icon {\n                  ...icon\n                }\n                text\n              }\n              infos\n            }\n            carouselButtonAllyStrings\n          }\n          guaranteedAnalytics {\n            ...analytics\n          }\n          personalisedDeal {\n            ...carPhrase\n          }\n          offerPositionClickAnalytics {\n            ...analytics\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      carRentalLocations {\n        routeType\n        pickUpLocation {\n          ...carSearchLocation\n        }\n        dropOffLocation {\n          ...carSearchLocation\n        }\n        searchAccessibility\n      }\n      changeRentalLocation {\n        link {\n          ... on CarActionableItem {\n            text\n          }\n        }\n        placeHolder {\n          ... on CarPhraseText {\n            text\n          }\n        }\n        primary {\n          ... on CarPhraseText {\n            text\n          }\n        }\n        secondary {\n          ... on CarPhraseText {\n            text\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      summary {\n        title\n        dynamicTitle {\n          ...carPhrase\n        }\n        pageTitle\n        includedFeeFooter {\n          title\n          description\n        }\n        carRecommendations {\n          ...carRecommendations\n        }\n      }\n      filterNoMatchMessage {\n        messagingCard {\n          ...messagingCard\n        }\n        allOffersTextSeparator\n      }\n      loadMoreAction {\n        action {\n          ...carAction\n        }\n        icon {\n          ...icon\n        }\n        searchPagination {\n          size\n          startingIndex\n        }\n        text\n      }\n      loyaltyInfo {\n        __typename\n        ... on CarPhraseText {\n          text\n        }\n        ... on CarActionableItem {\n          ...carActionableItem\n        }\n        ... on CarPhraseMark {\n          text\n          name\n          url {\n            value\n            relativePath\n          }\n          description\n        }\n      }\n      oneKeyInfo {\n        isOneKeyEnrolled\n      }\n      sortAndFilter {\n        title\n        close {\n          ...icon\n        }\n        appliedFilterCount\n        clearButtonTitle\n        sections {\n          title\n          fields {\n            __typename\n            primary\n            secondary\n            ...SingleSelectionFragment\n            ...MultiSelectionFragment\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      carAppliedSortAndFilters {\n        appliedSortAndFilters {\n          id\n          text\n          value\n          crossIcon {\n            ...icon\n          }\n          analytics {\n            ...clientSideAnalytics\n          }\n        }\n      }\n      shareFeedbackAction {\n        text\n        button {\n          ...carActionableItem\n        }\n      }\n      adsTargetingData {\n        uuid\n        siteId\n        pageName\n        origin\n        dest\n        locResolver\n        dateStart\n        dateEnd\n        adProvider\n      }\n      recommendedSortDisclaimer {\n        ...carPhrase\n      }\n      recommendedSortExplanation {\n        content {\n          ...carPhrase\n        }\n        feedback {\n          ...searchUserFeedback\n        }\n        closeAnalytics {\n          ...analytics\n        }\n      }\n      makeModelDisclaimer {\n        ...carPhrase\n      }\n      map {\n        title\n        text\n        closeIcon {\n          ...icon\n        }\n        closeAction {\n          ...carAction\n        }\n        center {\n          ...coordinates\n        }\n        bounds {\n          northeast {\n            ...coordinates\n          }\n          southwest {\n            ...coordinates\n          }\n        }\n        zoomLevel\n        markers {\n          __typename\n          type\n          action {\n            ...carAction\n          }\n          coordinates {\n            ...coordinates\n          }\n          ... on CarItemCardMapMarker {\n            itemCard {\n              ... on CarMapSearchLocationCard {\n                title\n                text\n              }\n              ... on CarMapPickupLocationCard {\n                vendorLocationId\n                placeId\n                vendorImage {\n                  ...image\n                }\n                vendorReview {\n                  rating\n                  superlative\n                  totalCount\n                  richRatingText {\n                    ...detailsRichText\n                  }\n                }\n                address\n                shortAddress\n                distance\n                superlative\n                priceSummary {\n                  lead {\n                    ...priceInfo\n                  }\n                  total {\n                    ...priceInfo\n                  }\n                  strikeThroughFirst\n                  loyaltyPointsOption {\n                    formattedPoints\n                    leadingCaption\n                    pointsFirst\n                  }\n                  accessibility\n                }\n                seeCarsButtonText\n                action {\n                  ...carAction\n                }\n              }\n            }\n          }\n        }\n        mapButton {\n          url {\n            value\n          }\n          text\n          action {\n            ...carAction\n          }\n        }\n        filterTitle\n        mapSearchThisAreaButton {\n          text\n          action {\n            ...carAction\n          }\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    carsErrorContent {\n      icon {\n        ...icon\n      }\n      heading\n      subText\n      analytics {\n        linkName\n        referrerId\n      }\n      errorEventName\n      locationAnalytics {\n        linkName\n        referrerId\n      }\n    }\n    carRecommendationContent {\n      ... on CarRecommendations {\n        ...carRecommendations\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment messagingCard on CarMessagingCard {\n  title\n  cardTitle {\n    ...carPhrase\n  }\n  description\n  descriptions\n  cardDescriptions {\n    ...carPhrase\n  }\n  mark\n  image {\n    description\n    url\n  }\n  illustrationURL {\n    value\n  }\n  icon {\n    ...icon\n  }\n  links {\n    text\n    url {\n      value\n      relativePath\n    }\n    icon {\n      ...icon\n    }\n    action {\n      actionType\n      analytics {\n        linkName\n        referrerId\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  dialog {\n    title\n    buttonText\n    text\n    content {\n      header {\n        ...carPhrase\n      }\n      body {\n        title {\n          ...carPhrase\n        }\n        body {\n          ...carPhrase\n        }\n      }\n      footer {\n        ...carPhrase\n      }\n    }\n    type\n  }\n  carRecommendations {\n    ...carRecommendations\n  }\n  analytics {\n    ...analytics\n  }\n}\n\nfragment carPhrase on CarPhrase {\n  __typename\n  ... on CarPhraseText {\n    text\n  }\n  ... on CarPhrasePairText {\n    richText {\n      ...detailsRichText\n    }\n    richSubText {\n      ...detailsRichText\n    }\n  }\n  ... on CarPhraseIconText {\n    text\n    icon {\n      ...icon\n    }\n  }\n  ... on CarActionableItem {\n    ...carActionableItem\n  }\n  ... on CarDialogConfidenceMessage {\n    ...carDialogConfidenceMessage\n  }\n  ... on CarsRichText {\n    value\n    style\n    theme\n  }\n  ... on CarPhraseMark {\n    text\n    name\n    url {\n      value\n      relativePath\n    }\n    description\n  }\n  ... on CarOfferBadge {\n    icon {\n      ...icon\n    }\n    mark {\n      id\n      url {\n        value\n      }\n    }\n    text\n    badgeTheme: theme\n  }\n}\n\nfragment detailsRichText on CarsRichText {\n  value\n  theme\n  style\n}\n\nfragment icon on Icon {\n  description\n  id\n  withBackground\n  size\n}\n\nfragment carActionableItem on CarActionableItem {\n  url {\n    value\n    relativePath\n  }\n  action {\n    ...carAction\n  }\n  text\n  icon {\n    ...icon\n  }\n}\n\nfragment carAction on CarAction {\n  actionType\n  accessibility\n  analytics {\n    ...analytics\n  }\n}\n\nfragment analytics on CarAnalytics {\n  linkName\n  referrerId\n}\n\nfragment carDialogConfidenceMessage on CarDialogConfidenceMessage {\n  text\n  icon {\n    ...icon\n  }\n  openDialogAction {\n    ...carAction\n  }\n  dialogContent {\n    title\n    text\n    buttonText\n    content {\n      header {\n        ...dialogContentCarPhrase\n      }\n      body {\n        __typename\n        title {\n          ...dialogContentCarPhrase\n        }\n        body {\n          ...dialogContentCarPhrase\n        }\n      }\n      footer {\n        ...dialogContentCarPhrase\n      }\n    }\n    type\n  }\n  iconMobileRender\n}\n\nfragment dialogContentCarPhrase on CarPhrase {\n  __typename\n  ... on CarPhraseText {\n    text\n  }\n  ... on CarPhraseIconText {\n    text\n    icon {\n      ...icon\n    }\n  }\n  ... on CarsRichText {\n    value\n    style\n  }\n  ... on CarActionableItem {\n    ...carActionableItem\n  }\n}\n\nfragment carRecommendations on CarRecommendations {\n  __typename\n  heading\n  analytics {\n    linkName\n    referrerId\n  }\n  carRecommendationsCards {\n    ...carRecommendationCard\n  }\n}\n\nfragment carRecommendationCard on CarRecommendationCard {\n  __typename\n  icon {\n    ...icon\n  }\n  action {\n    ...carAction\n  }\n  ... on DateTimeRecommendationCard {\n    icon {\n      ...icon\n    }\n    text {\n      ...detailsRichText\n    }\n    subText {\n      ...carPhrase\n    }\n    action {\n      ...carAction\n    }\n  }\n  ... on LocationRecommendationCard {\n    icon {\n      ...icon\n    }\n    location {\n      ...detailsRichText\n    }\n    city {\n      ...carPhrase\n    }\n    distanceText {\n      ...carPhrase\n    }\n    action {\n      ...carAction\n    }\n    pickUpLocation {\n      ...carSearchLocation\n    }\n  }\n  ... on PartnerRecommendationCard {\n    icon {\n      ...icon\n    }\n    action {\n      ...carAction\n    }\n    analytics {\n      ...analytics\n    }\n    image {\n      ...image\n    }\n    title {\n      ...carPhrase\n    }\n    subText {\n      ...carPhrase\n    }\n    button {\n      ...carActionableItem\n    }\n    dialog {\n      ... on PartnerRecommendationDialog {\n        title {\n          ...carPhrase\n        }\n        subTitle {\n          ...carPhrase\n        }\n        text {\n          ...carPhrase\n        }\n        button {\n          ...carActionableItem\n        }\n        closeDialog {\n          ...carAction\n        }\n        content {\n          ... on PartnerRecommendationDialogContent {\n            title {\n              ...carPhrase\n            }\n            body {\n              ...carPhrase\n            }\n            confidenceMessage {\n              ...carPhrase\n            }\n          }\n        }\n        image {\n          ...image\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n  ... on AlternateRecommendationCard {\n    icon {\n      ...icon\n    }\n    action {\n      ...carAction\n    }\n    analytics {\n      ...analytics\n    }\n    image {\n      ...image\n    }\n    title {\n      ...carPhrase\n    }\n    subText {\n      ...carPhrase\n    }\n    button {\n      ...carActionableItem\n    }\n  }\n  ... on LimitedResultMessageOnRecommendationCard {\n    icon {\n      ...icon\n    }\n    action {\n      ...carAction\n    }\n    recommendationDialog {\n      title\n      buttonText\n      text\n      content {\n        header {\n          ...carPhrase\n        }\n        body {\n          title {\n            ...carPhrase\n          }\n          body {\n            ...carPhrase\n          }\n        }\n        footer {\n          ...carPhrase\n        }\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment carSearchLocation on CarSearchLocation {\n  shortName\n  fullName\n  regionId\n}\n\nfragment image on Image {\n  description\n  url\n}\n\nfragment badge on CarOfferBadge {\n  icon {\n    ...icon\n  }\n  text\n  theme\n  mark {\n    id\n    url {\n      value\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment feature on VehicleFeature {\n  icon {\n    ...icon\n  }\n  text\n  info {\n    vehicleFeatureDialog {\n      title\n      text\n      buttonText\n    }\n    carActionableItem {\n      ...carActionableItem\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment carOfferVendorLocationInfo on CarOfferVendorLocationInfo {\n  locationId\n  placeId\n  icon {\n    ...icon\n  }\n  text\n  locationSubInfo\n}\n\nfragment offerPriceSummary on CarPriceSummary {\n  discountBadge {\n    ...badge\n  }\n  lead {\n    ...priceInfo\n  }\n  total {\n    ...priceInfo\n  }\n  strikeThroughFirst\n  loyaltyPointsOption {\n    formattedPoints\n    leadingCaption\n    pointsFirst\n  }\n  accessibility\n  reference {\n    additionalInfo\n    price {\n      ...money\n    }\n    qualifier\n  }\n  paymentInfo {\n    icon {\n      ...icon\n    }\n    text\n    additionalPaymentInfo\n  }\n  priceAdditionalInfo\n}\n\nfragment priceInfo on CarPriceInfo {\n  price {\n    ...money\n  }\n  accessibility\n  qualifier\n  formattedValue\n}\n\nfragment money on Money {\n  amount\n  formatted\n  currencyInfo {\n    code\n    name\n    symbol\n  }\n}\n\nfragment SingleSelectionFragment on ShoppingSelectionField {\n  primary\n  secondary\n  options {\n    ...FilterOption\n  }\n  expando {\n    ...Expando\n  }\n}\n\nfragment FilterOption on ShoppingSelectableFilterOption {\n  id\n  value\n  primary\n  secondary\n  description\n  accessibility\n  selected\n  disabled\n  icon {\n    ...icon\n  }\n  analytics {\n    ...clientSideAnalytics\n  }\n}\n\nfragment clientSideAnalytics on ClientSideAnalytics {\n  linkName\n  referrerId\n}\n\nfragment Expando on ShoppingSelectionExpando {\n  expandLabel\n  collapseLabel\n  visible\n  threshold\n  minimalHeight\n  analytics {\n    ...clientSideAnalytics\n  }\n}\n\nfragment MultiSelectionFragment on ShoppingMultiSelectionField {\n  primary\n  primaryIcon {\n    ...icon\n  }\n  secondary\n  options {\n    ...FilterOption\n  }\n  expando {\n    ...Expando\n  }\n}\n\nfragment searchUserFeedback on UserFeedback {\n  userSurveyTitle\n  options {\n    inputHeading\n    inputTextPlaceholder\n    option {\n      ...carActionableItem\n    }\n  }\n  submitConfirmation\n  submit {\n    ...carActionableItem\n  }\n}\n\nfragment coordinates on Coordinates {\n  latitude\n  longitude\n}\n",
  "variables": {
    "context": {
      "siteId": 1,
      "locale": "en_US",
      "eapid": 0,
      "currency": "USD",
      "device": {
        "type": "DESKTOP"
      },
      "identity": {
        "duaid": "66f18af8-5ac4-46e6-b904-e297a8851b49",
        "expUserId": "-1",
        "tuid": "-1",
        "authState": "ANONYMOUS"
      },
      "privacyTrackingState": "CAN_TRACK",
      "debugContext": {
        "abacusOverrides": [],
        "alterMode": "RELEASED"
      }
    },
    "primaryCarSearchCriteria": {
      "pickUpLocation": {
        "searchTerm": "Cancun, Quintana Roo, Mexico (CUN-Cancun Intl.)",
        "regionId": "5133635",
        "isExactLocationSearch": false
      },
      "pickUpDateTime": {
        "day": 25,
        "month": 10,
        "year": 2023,
        "hour": 10,
        "minute": 30,
        "second": 0
      },
      "dropOffDateTime": {
        "day": 26,
        "month": 10,
        "year": 2023,
        "hour": 10,
        "minute": 30,
        "second": 0
      }
    },
    "secondaryCriteria": {
      "booleans": [
        {
          "id": "SALES_UNLOCKED",
          "value": false
        }
      ],
      "selections": [
        {
          "id": "searchId",
          "value": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    "shoppingContext": null
  },
  "operationName": "CarSearchV3"
}`;

let config = {
  method: 'post',
  maxBodyLength: Infinity,
  url: 'https://www.expedia.com/graphql',
  headers: { 
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/117.0.2045.60', 
    'X-Page-Id':'page.Car-Search,C,20', 
    'Client-Info':'bernie-cars-shopping-web,pwa,us-east-1', 
    'Host':'www.expedia.com', 
    'Content-Type':'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 
    'Accept':'*/*',
    'Cookie':'DUAID=31273849-18f8-47a2-a7f6-2b152db124a3; EG_SESSIONTOKEN=dFwUeviiMf7NwP1ASQjxIVZh6q6lfbl5qrQUO9rzEkOUsk:YNYq9Mfy9YAuhZ0yB7yH2ODV4OaZ2274-36C0o3AF1nXtR00oJLxGd62bmdrIbd_IPkOjewRKQp_nWhisEWOtg; MC1=GUID=3127384918f847a2a7f62b152db124a3; _abck=41529DD02E2FECAF4E4CC208AF5C0459~-1~YAAQXqb3vQVscvGKAQAAHxfjIAqfs0SOzFUp73mtrxVgYeQj8JWhYKpx3JBEjfTAqq+ABRLVfv+mTWpqjprCFCR/nqGxmeYNmAT246oGscwcbFvLfyNNqYrrRnfAcd1CZMN45jriIpRL8kKIWFKnG4cza+xZ7ya7z2Z7qFZT50SGlKBC5lCcUqSHsol2trSvVhqPUsUQq4hXZASJLlHbcZP7HAJBBZ+muxcB6ln0N2w9zkWt1Ju5FCmng8nRKh2VfOZQzYL5ZJ8EK4Gg9O7ZwX5ZFPLOZZ0IoVob9L++BJI8JquVt+sQj3tBGRyNIPb52IdEyekSvJygwWMubTGALsrur5rMirk8lpxDwFErSc2zDJhCDgicxAzTS072pQ==~-1~-1~-1; cesc=%7B%22marketingClick%22%3A%5B%22false%22%2C1697067970316%5D%2C%22hitNumber%22%3A%5B%2229%22%2C1697067970316%5D%2C%22visitNumber%22%3A%5B%221%22%2C1697063835386%5D%2C%22entryPage%22%3A%5B%22page.Car-Search%22%2C1697067970316%5D%7D',
  },
  data : data,

};

axios.request(config)
.then((response) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: `doCurl()` only has 4 parameters, why are you calling it with 6 arguments?

Comment: you don't need the `Host:` header if it's the same host as in the URL.

Comment: At first glance it looks like it should work. Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Barmar I forgot to remove the two parameters that you see in docurl. Removing or leaving the Host gives me the following error in node js axios:
**Request failed with status code 403**.